# Sorting nested array not returning sorted results

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, which seems to be doing the correct thing, but when I log the array object it never changes:

```js
let data = [
    {'country': 'AB', 'state': 'DE'},
    {'country': 'US', 'state': 'CA'},
    {'country': 'AB', 'state': 'DE'},
    {'country': 'US', 'state': 'MI'},
    {'country': 'RU', 'state': null}
];
function sortFunc(a, b) {
    let val = a['country'] < b['country'];
    console.log(a['country'], b['country'], val);
    return +val;
}
data.sort(sortFunc);
console.log(data);
```

What is the issue with the above code?

Comment: The function passed to `sort` is a comparator, which should return a negative number if the first element is less than the second, a positive one if it's greater, and `0` if they're equivalent.  It would be easy enough to write a custom `sort` function which took this sort of predicate, if you preferred this style.  But it wouldn't be a method of `Array`, then.

Comment: I know you're self-answering, but is there a reason this isn't a duplicate of [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison) or [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)?

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` function needs to go both ways and return `0` if equal or `-1` or `1` -- the above function just returns `1` or `0`. Here would be a proper version:

```js
let data = [
    {'country': 'AB', 'state': 'DE'},
    {'country': 'US', 'state': 'CA'},
    {'country': 'AB', 'state': 'DE'},
    {'country': 'US', 'state': 'MI'},
    {'country': 'RU', 'state': null}
];
function sortFunc(_a, _b) {
    let [a,b] = [_a['country'], _b['country']];
    if (a===b)      return 0;
    else if (a>b)   return 1;
    else            return -1;
}
data.sort(sortFunc);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you want to sort it in ascending or descending, so just figure it out yourself from ternary operator. Rest I guess its working as you expect.

```js
let data = [
    {'country': 'AB', 'state': 'DE'},
    {'country': 'US', 'state': 'CA'},
    {'country': 'AB', 'state': 'DE'},
    {'country': 'US', 'state': 'MI'},
    {'country': 'RU', 'state': null}
];
function sortFunc(a, b) {
    return a['country'] < b['country']?1:-1;
}
data = data.sort(sortFunc);
console.log(data);
```

[image]